# How does Spark SQL alter table work under the hood?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Say I have a table saved as parquet files. I believe these are read / append-only. So when I add / remove / change columns via alter table, does Spark process the entire set of parquet files and write new ones?

Is that super expensive? (and requires locking the entire table right?)

Comment: Altering table changes metadata only.

Comment: Think of it for a moment. Why would you need to change the data files?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz because schema evolves, columns get added/removed/etc

Comment: Yep. And why would you need to change existing files?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Existing and new data belong to the same tables (using hive metastore), and the table schema needs to stay up to date. I don't think I want to create a new table everytime there's schema change

Comment: This still doesn't answer why existing data files should be changed.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz for example, a column gets renamed. Does that not require existing data to change?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz or a column gets changed from string to struct, maybe after dozens of schema changes and there's a forgotten collision

Comment: No ,it does not.  It can be handled on the Metadata level. You only need to document the original name and the latest name.

Comment: Are you able to change a string to struct? Better check it

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I checked, and it appears ALTER TABLE only supports adding and renaming columns, not removing columns or changing. Looks like I would manually rewrite the table if I want columns changed / dropped.